# das / Auto / fahren / lernen

Tags: spelling

Challenged by another thread, I wondered **how many (correct) spellings** there are for **das / Auto / fahren / lernen** (i.e. sentences with these words in that particular order).

Answer (score 4):

I found three.

1.

> Er muss das Auto fahren lernen.

"das" refers to: das Auto
He has to learn to drive the car.
He has to learn to drive that particular car.

2.

> Er muss das Autofahren lernen.

"das" refers to: das Autofahren, das Fahren.
(He has to learn the "driving a car".)
He has to learn to drive a car.

3.

> Das Auto-fahren-Lernen ist nicht leicht.

"das" refers to: das Auto-fahren-Lernen, das Lernen.
It is spelled with hyphens because of §43.
(The "learning how to drive a car" is not easy.)
It't not easy to learn to drive a car.

*Update:*
To continue the pattern of 1. and 2.

> Er muss das Auto-fahren-Lernen ernster nehmen.

(He has to take the "learning how to drive a car" more seriously.)

Comment: I suggest as an alternative spelling *Er muss das Autofahrenlernen ernster nehmen*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Why? How would you say this fits rule §43? ("Man setzt Bindestriche in substantivisch gebrauchten Zusammensetzungen
(Aneinanderreihungen), insbesondere bei substantivisch
gebrauchten Infinitiven mit mehr als zwei Bestandteilen.")